# Type deduction for lamda wrapped in template function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, g++, c++20

I implemented custom alternative of `std::bind` version like below:

```
  template <typename F, typename ... Ts>                                           
  constexpr auto curry(F &&f, Ts ... args) {                                       
    return [&](auto&& ... args2) {                                                 
      return f(std::forward<Ts...>(args...), args2...);                            
    };                                                                             
  }
```

This function gets function and pack of the arguments to be applied, and returns lambda which is `f` with partially applied arguments `args`.

Also, for test this code, I have a function, which gets 2 arguments and just returns first one:

```
  template <typename T1, typename T2>                                          
  constexpr T1 fconst(T1 &&x, T2&&) {                                          
    return x;                                                                  
  }
```

When I use my `curry` function like below:

```
int main() {                                                                       
                                                                                   
  auto z2 = curry(fconst, 5);                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                   
  return 0;                                                                        
}
```

I get an error that compiler can't deduce `F` type:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘curry(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int)’
   17 |   auto z2 = curry(fconst, 5);
candidate: ‘template<class F, class ... Ts> constexpr auto curry(F&&, Ts ...)’
   15 |   constexpr auto curry(F &&f, Ts ... args) {
      |                  ^~~~~
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘F’
   17 |   auto z2 = curry(fconst, 5);
```

But when I implement `curry` function as macro instead of template function:

```
#define curry(f, args...) \                                                        
  [&](auto&& ... args2) { \                                                        
    return f(args, args2...); \                                                    
  };
```

My main code compiles successfully.

I use g++11 and c++20 enabled.

My questions are:

1. Why compiler can't deduce `F` type for template, but can do it when pass lambda as is?
2. Can my `curry` function be implemented using template function, or macro is only possible way to do it?

Comment: Not an answer but you for sure do not want to capture `curry::args` by reference. They will become dangling after the lambda is returned. Also use `<decltype(args)>` for forwarding.

Comment: Issue is to deduce `fconst` (which is template). `auto z2 = curry([](auto&& first, auto&&){ return first; }, 5);` or `auto z2 = curry(fconst<int, int>, 5);` would works.

Comment: @Quimby Do you mean that `Ts...` must be `Ts&&...` in arguments?

Comment: @Shadasviar That's up to you really, either can work, depending on how you capture them later. But you cannot capture them by ref.

Comment: @Shadasviar: `Ts&&` would still be problematic as in your example with `5`. `return [=](auto&& ... args2)` would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your `curry` is dangerous because the lambda inside captures local arguments by reference. As soon as `curry` return you've got dangling refs.

Correct version is:

```
  template <typename F, typename ... Ts>                                           
  constexpr auto curry(F &&f, Ts ... args) {                                       
    return [...args=std::move(args), f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&& ... args2) mutable {                                                 
      return std::invoke(f,args..., std::forward<decltype(args2)>(args2)...);                            
    };                                                                             
  }
```

- There are two equal styles shown by `f`, `args` handling.

  - Either copy the at the caller side - `args`.
  - Or copy/move (by forward) at capture time.
- (Parameter pack capture is C++20). There is an uglier workaround using tuples and `std::apply`, ask if you need it.
- `std::bind` never moves its captured arguments, they are always passed as lvalues to the callee. This makes repeated calls safe.
- `args2` should be correctly forwarded.

Unfortunately there is no macro-less solution. This is the inherent issue with sets of overloaded functions. One cannot pass such sets around, there simply is no support in C++ for that. There were some papers trying to fix that - I know of [P1170R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1170r0.html). But none were accepted so far.

The workaround is essentially what you came up with and why your second example works - the macro is capable of pasting the function name, no matter whether it is overloaded (or what it is at all really).

```
#define overload_set(overloaded_f) \                                                        
  [](auto&& ... args) { \                                                        
    return overloaded_f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);} \
```

This is in-place perfect-forwarding lambda with copy-pasted `overloaded_f` symbol inside. Still, one cannot take an address of this(or rather shouldn't) like any other ordinary function, but it can be passed to e.g. `curry`.

##### Full example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename F, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto curry(F&& f, Ts... args) {
    return [... args = std::move(args),
            f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&... args2) mutable {
        return f(args..., std::forward<decltype(args2)>(args2)...);
    };
}
template <typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr T1 fconst(T1&& x, T2&&y) {
    std::cout<<"Value x:" << x<<'\n';
    std::cout<<"Value y:" << y<<'\n';
    return x;
}

#define overload_set(overloaded_f)                              \
  [&](auto&&... args) {                                         \
    return overloaded_f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); \
    }

struct Foo{
    Foo()=default;
    Foo(Foo&&)=default;
    Foo(const Foo&)=delete;

    operator int(){ return 42;}
};

int main() { 
    // Overloaded function can now be stored in a lambda.
    auto stored_set= overload_set(fconst);
    // And called as ordinary function.
    auto ret =stored_set(1.0, 2.0); 
    std::cout<<"Returned value: " <<ret <<'\n';
    // Overloaded set now can be passed around.
    // But it is a functor, not a function.
    auto curried_fnc= curry(overload_set(fconst),1.0);
    // Curry works
    auto ret2 = curried_fnc(2.0);
    std::cout<<"Returned value: " <<ret2<<'\n';

    // Move-only values work too.
    std::cout<<"Curry move\n";
    curried_fnc(Foo{}); 
}
```

**Output**

```
Value x:1
Value y:2
Returned value: 1
Value x:1
Value y:2
Returned value: 1
Curry move 
Value x:1
Value y:42
```

Comment: I'd perfect-forward the args into the capture, i.e. `Ts &&... args`, and then `...args = std::forward<Ts>(args)`.

Comment: I prefer to use `std::invoke` to invoke `f` since it may be a member function pointer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, that is also possible, I wanted to show both ways - `f` and `args`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Good catch, that is the better solution.